# "Reduce" in useSelector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't speak English very well but i will try it.

I have been looking for this for some time and i could not find a clear solution, I'm using React Hook for make a e-commerce and in my global store a have a list products that are in my cart.

I need count products for show total quantity, **how i can run ".reduce" of my products list?**

**¿Is necesary create a useState?**

Products list of my cart, it have this schema

```
[{
    id: 5,
    quantity: 3
},{
    id: 23,
    quantity: 1
}]
```

I have thought of doing it in the following ways

**OPTION 1: (without useState, it's valid?)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Cart = () => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.myCart); // list cart
  const count = cart.reduce((total, product) => {
    return total + product.quantity;
  }, 0);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{count}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

**OPTION 2: This option has a little delay when show count**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const Cart = () => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.myCart); // list cart
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0) 

  useEffect(() => {

    setCount(cart.reduce((total, product) => {
        return total + product.quantity;
      }, 0));

  }, [cart])


  return (
    <div>
      <span>{count}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

what is the best way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the first option. The second version does the same thing but with an extra render and more code. What's the advantage of that?

Comment: This might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you are only displaying the count you can also move the reduction into the selector function callback. Selectors allow you to return state however a component consumes it.

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const cartCountSelector = state =>
  state.myCart.reduce((total, product) => {
    return total + product.quantity;
  }, 0);

const Cart = () => {
  const count = useSelector(cartCountSelector); // list cart count

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{count}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cart;
```

Comment: Great! Thank so much

Comment: Also, is it valid to do something like OPTION 1 when I need only displaying value ?

Comment: @Nik020 Sure. I only factored out into a selector function for better code reuse. If any other component subscribes to the store, it can simply import and use that selector function.